# Show that the locus is straight line.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> The position vector of $C$ is $-3\vec i - 2\vec j + p\vec k$.
>
> Show that, if $p$ is a variable, then the locus of $C$ is a straight line and find the two unit direction vectors along this line.

Intuitively I think that the locus will be along the unit $k$ vector. But I am not able to figure out how to go about proving this.

Can you guys point me in the right direction? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Not "along", but certainly "parallel"...

Comment: Details depend on how definitions have been given. But take distinct $p_1$, $p_2$, and general $p$, giving vectors $v_1$, $v_2$, $v$.  Compare $v_2-v_1$ with $v-v_1$.  You can even take $p_1=0$, $p_2=1$.

Comment: Got it! $v_2 - v_1 = \lambda (v - v_1)$. Thus these vectors are $\parallel$ with a common point, and hence points are collinear. Locus is a straight line. Thanks @Andre.

Comment: @mathguy80: It is perfectly normal for people who ask questions to post answers, and to accept the answer. If you feel like doing it, and have trouble with the TeX, I or someone else can fix things.

Comment: "Can you guys point me in the right direction?" Pun intended?

Comment: hah! unintentional :)

Comment: Answering your own question feel's a little odd to me, particularly when I didn't quite figure it out...

Comment: Doesn't sound odd to me. I answer questions that, many years ago, I learned how to solve, from seeing something similar somewhere. In your case it was just more recent.

Comment: I see your point, I'll try to incorporate the comment in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding Andre's comment as answer to close this question.

Let $p_1, p_2$ be distinct points with vectors $\vec c_1, \vec c_2$.

Then,

$$
\vec c - \vec c_1 = (p - p_1) \vec k
$$

And,
$$
\begin{align}
\vec c_2 - \vec c_1 &= (p_2 - p_1) \vec k \\
&= \dfrac{(p_2 - p_1)}{(p - p_1)} (p - p_1) \vec k \\
&= \dfrac{(p_2 - p_1)}{(p - p_1)} (\vec c - \vec c_1) \\
&= \lambda (\vec c - \vec c_1)
\end{align}
$$

Hence, $\vec c, \vec c_1, \vec c_2$ are parallel with a common point. Thus points $p, p_1, p_2$ are collinear. Hence locus of $C$ is a straight line for variable $p$.